# How to query a datetime column to find dates that may be out of order in a case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that displays orders with a pickup and sometimes multiple deliveries. All stops on the order are giving a sequence number based on how it was entered. Sometimes we can fat finger a date and the 3rd stop out of 5 is not in chronological order with the rest. I need a case statement that populates either 'Yes' or 'No' if there is a date entered out of order. I tried the to create the following Case statement, but it doesn't work, it returns Yes, when it is no, and sometimes is just blank.

```
Select Top 1 Case 
When Exists (Select Count(*) from stops having Count(*) = '2') Then Case
When s1.stp_schdtlatest<s2.stp_schdtlatest
Then 'Yes'
When Exists (Select Count(*) from stops having Count(*) = '3') Then Case
When s1.stp_schdtlatest < s2.stp_schdtlatest and s2.stp_schdtlatest < s3.stp_schdtlatest
Then 'Yes'
When Exists (Select Count(*) from stops having Count(*) = '4') Then Case
When (s1.stp_schdtlatest < s2.stp_schdtlatest) and (s2.stp_schdtlatest < s3.stp_schdtlatest) and (s3.stp_schdtlatest < s4.stp_schdtlatest)
Then 'Yes'
When Exists (Select Count(*) from stops having Count(*) >= '5') Then Case
When (s1.stp_schdtlatest<s2.stp_schdtlatest) and (s2.stp_schdtlatest<s3.stp_schdtlatest) and (s3.stp_schdtlatest<s4.stp_schdtlatest) and (s4.stp_schdtlatest<s5.stp_schdtlatest)
Then 'Yes'
Else 'No-Out of Sequence'
End
End
End
End
End as 'Sequenced?'
from legheader l 
Inner Join stops on stops.lgh_number = l.lgh_number
Inner join stops s1 on s1.lgh_number = l.lgh_number and s1.stp_mfh_sequence = '1'
Inner join stops s2 on s2.lgh_number = l.lgh_number and s2.stp_mfh_sequence = '2'
Inner join stops s3 on s3.lgh_number = l.lgh_number and s3.stp_mfh_sequence = '3'
Inner join stops s4 on s4.lgh_number = l.lgh_number and s4.stp_mfh_sequence = '4'
Inner join stops s5 on s5.lgh_number = l.lgh_number and s5.stp_mfh_sequence = '5'
where lgh_outstatus in ('AVL','PLN','DSP','STD') and l.lgh_number = 276735
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a data sample and the expected output for that case. Like this it's quite difficult to understand the problem. :-)

Comment: If you're nesting expressions (`CASE` is an expression not a statement) good use of whitespace is a must. It's impossible to tell what `END` and what `WHEN` belongs to which. From the looks, do you even need all those `CASE` expressions? Couldn't this be serviced with just 1?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It might be easier to use a windowing function like ROW_NUMBER. It is difficult for me to determine from your current query exactly how you need the data. But something like this should get you some usable results, and hopefully point you in the direction to get exactly the results you need...

```
SELECT relevant_data
   , CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.stp_mfh_sequence) <> ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.stp_schdtlatest )
          THEN 'Out of Sequence'
          ELSE 'In Sequence'
     END AS seqState
FROM legheader AS l 
INNER JOIN stops AS ON l.lgh_number = s.lgh_number
WHERE l.lgh_outstatus in ('AVL','PLN','DSP','STD') 
   AND l.lgh_number = 276735
;
```

Note: As I write this, I realize that once you have one out of order, many that follow it will be considered out of order. *(If seq 2 entry has a time > seq 4, then the "out of order" state will persist until seq 5.)*

You can also extend this to multiple lgh_numbers with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.lgh_number ORDER BY ...)`